# Dropdown menu populate into textbox using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I have a problem in Codeigniter which is calling the `data(mysql)` in dropdown menu then populate into text-box

```
    <tr>
    <td>Item No:</td>
<td><select type="text" id="inventoryitemno" name="inventoryitemno" value="getitemno" onChange="getitemnoetc(inventoryitemno);" >
    <?php
          foreach($itemno as $row){
          echo "<option id=".$row->prod_id.">".$row->prod_itemno."</option>";

          }
                                ?>

                                </select>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Description:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="idesc" name="idesc"/></td> <!-- disabled="disable" -->
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>UOM:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="inventoryuom" name="inventoryuom" /></td><!-- disabled="disable" -->
                        </tr>   
                        <tr>
```

here's the JavaScript; trying to call the data

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getitemno(str)
{
    ???????
}
</script>
```

here's my **CI_model**

```
public function getitemnoetc($inventoryitemno){
    $inventoryitemno=$_GET["inventoryitemno"];

    $this->load->database();
    $data = $this->db->query('select prod_id, prod_desc, prod_selluom from product where prod_itemno ='.$inventoryitemno.';');
    return $data->result();         
}/*end of function*/
```

I hope u get it my question.

Comment: You should use ajax - check jquery post function: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/, or, i don't actually get question...

Comment: I dont get question either. Why aren't you using Codeigniters `form_dropdown()`?

Comment: here's what im trying to say:

when u click dropdown, it will fetch the data of itemno, prod_desc,prod_selluom
then i just wanted to do is populate to the textbox named: 
idesc and inventoryuom.

i hope u can help me. thanks in advance.

Comment: i revised my question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160196/php-codeigniter-fetch-data-in-dropdown-and-populate-into-textbox